# vim e518: unknown option:

Tags: vim

I have a text file on a unix system.  The following text file content creates the problem:

```
good: ok line
vi: bad line
ok: ok line
```

So if I run: `vim test.txt`, I get the following error:

```
"test.txt" 3L, 39C
Error detected while processing modelines:
line    2:
E518: Unknown option: bad
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I delete my `~/.vimrc`, the error disappears. But what is weird is that, even with an empty `~/.vimrc` file, the error appears.

I understand that it's because the line starts with `vi:` that the error is created, but I don't understand why or how to fix this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `vi: bad line` line is in a format that Vim recognizes as a [modeline](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#modeline), as mentioned in the error message.  Modelines allow one to set options within a file.

The reason it isn't triggered when you don't have a `~/.vimrc` is because Vim requires you have `'nocompatible'` set for modelines to be enabled by default, since it is a Vim-specific feature.  The existence of `~/.vimrc` is enough for Vim to switch from vi-compatible mode to nocompatible, though, which will result in the `'modeline'` option also being set.

For future reference, you can easily find help topics in Vim via `:help topic<Tab>`.  In this case, `:help modeline<Tab>` would have given you a few topics to look into which explain this feature and how to control it.

Comment: Thanks you. I'll mark this as accepted answer because it explains both what it is happening and why (presence of vimrc).

Comment: so vim understands last `n` lines as `modelines` (i.e. vim settings) so its desirable that one should keep last `n` lines of his code either empty lines or actual `vim modelines` to avoid this error.

Answer (score 16):

You could turn off modeline processing with

```
:set nomodeline
```

See `:help modeline` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Under `:help auto-setting` you find this paragraph:

```
3. If you start editing a new file, and the 'modeline' option is on, a
   number of lines at the beginning and end of the file are checked for
   modelines.  This is explained here. 

There are two forms of modelines.  The first form:
    [text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]{options}

[text]      any text or empty
{white}     at least one blank character (<Space> or <Tab>)
{vi:|vim:|ex:}  the string "vi:", "vim:" or "ex:"
[white]     optional white space
{options}   a list of option settings, separated with white space or ':',
        where each part between ':' is the argument for a ":set"
        command (can be empty)

Example:
   vi:noai:sw=3 ts=6 ~

The second form (this is compatible with some versions of Vi):

    [text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]se[t] {options}:[text]

[text]      any text or empty
{white}     at least one blank character (<Space> or <Tab>)
{vi:|vim:|ex:}  the string "vi:", "vim:" or "ex:"
[white]     optional white space
se[t]       the string "set " or "se " (note the space)
{options}   a list of options, separated with white space, which is the
        argument for a ":set" command
:       a colon
[text]      any text or empty

Example:
   /* vim: set ai tw=75: */ ~

The white space before {vi:|vim:|ex:} is required.  This minimizes the chance
that a normal word like "lex:" is caught.  There is one exception: "vi:" and
"vim:" can also be at the start of the line (for compatibility with version
3.0).  Using "ex:" at the start of the line will be ignored (this could be
short for "example:").
```

So, probably, in your ~/.vimrc you have a `set nomodeline`.

The line reading `vi: bad line` tries to set the option `bad` and `line` which cannot be set, hence the error.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by *jamessan'S* answer (+1), the `modeline` option is set through the setting of nocompatible by the mere existence of `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. The weird thing is that my line was just some line 696 in a 1000+ line (it's big /etc/group like file). But it solves my problem.