# E518: Unknown option: #

Tags: vim, vi

I copied the default settings from [vimconfig](http://vimconfig.com/) into my newly created .vimrc. After I start vim a bunch of the following messages apear:

```
E518: Unknown option: #
```

Reading [vim e518: unknown option:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583028/vim-e518-unknown-option) I'm asuming it has something to do with modeline:

> " [...] line is in a format that Vim recognizes as a modeline, as mentioned in the error message. Modelines allow one to set options within a file"
>   - jamessan

I don't really understand the Information given from `:help modeline`

Do I need to add a line like:

```
vi:noai:sw=3 ts=6 
vim: tw=77
```

Because `set: nomodeline` has no effect after I restart vim

*How do I make vim ignore the comments in my .vimrc ?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments in your `.vimrc` are starting with a double quote (`"`).

Example:

```
"
" using the mouse
"

" mouse - list of flags for using the mouse
set mouse=n

" mousemodel - "extend", "popup" or "popup_setpos"; what the right mouse button is used for
set mousem=extend
```

Comment: Yes. In the past I would just remove the part starting with the #. What keeps me wondering is why are the hashes kept as comments in the config from vimconfig.com ?!

Comment: I don't know why they are using hashes as comment line indicators. All I know (and can find over the internet) is that comment lines in the `.vimrc` file has to start with double quotes…

Comment: That site sure is weird. Anyway you can use `:%s/#\{1,}/"` to replace all the `#` with `"`

Comment: I just sent an email to the author asking him to change comment leaders.

Comment: He didn't do it!

Comment: To add to Evan's comment, I had to use `:%s/#\{1,}/\"`